# Indy server supports SSL 2, but it should not

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy10

Indy Delphi 10.1 Berlin.
My customer had the HTTPS connection checked (using Qualys SSL Labs). The report states: "This server supports SSL 2" plus other warnings but I guess they are related to this.
The code used is as follows:

```
SSLIOhandler:=TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.Create(NIL);
SSLIOhandler.SSLOptions.Method:=sslvTLSv1_2;
SSLIOhandler.SSLOptions.Mode:=sslmServer;
SSLIOhandler.OnVerifyPeer:=OnVerifyPeer;
SSLIOhandler.SSLOptions.SSLVersions:=[sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2];

HTTPServer:=TIdHTTPServer.Create(NIL);
HTTPServer.IOhandler:=SSLIOhandler;
```

I have read various posts but this area remains pretty much abacadabra to me. I limited the SSLVersions to just [sslvTLSv1_2] but the warning remains. What else can I do?

---

**Update**: Sorry to waste time. The Qualys test site apparently did not reload. I've restarted and retested and indeed it no longer complains about SSL2.

Next step is to pass its complaints about the ciphers, starting with TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA. I have a list of ciphers but can't find how to assign them. When I use e.g.

```
SSLOptions.CipherList:='TLS_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA';
```

I get an error: "SetCipher failed".

Comment: There is no possible way that SSLv2 (or SSLv3) could be supported using this code. Those versions are explicitly disabled using `SSL_CTX_set_options(SSL_OP_NO_SSLv2|3)` when not listed in the `Method` or `SSLVersions` property. See the code in `TIdSSLContext.InitContext()`.  `TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL` shares a single `SSL_CTX` across all accepted clients (see the code in `TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL.Accept()`).

Comment: Read OpenSSL's documentation: [`SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list()`](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.0.2/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list.html) and [Ciphers](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/Manual:Ciphers(1)).  `TLS_RSA_WITH_DES_CBC_SHA` is an individual cipher, which is not what `CipherList` is expecting.

Comment: Thank you very much. I've put the configuration settings in an ini file so that I could experiment. The server passes all security tests apart from 'forward secrecy' with the following settings. I had to upgrade the OpenSSL dll's.
Method=sslvTLSv1_2  
Ciphers=TLSv1:TLSv1.2:SSLv3:!RC4:!NULL-MD5:!NULL-SHA:!NULL-
SHA256:!DES-CBC-SHA:!DES-CBC3-SHA:!IDEA-CBC-SHA  
; versions :  
sslvSSLv2=N  
sslvSSLv23=N  
sslvSSLv3=N  
sslvTLSv1=Y  
sslvTLSv1_1=Y  
sslvTLSv1_2=Y