# Delphi Indy SSL parameters

Tags: delphi, ssl, indy

This is a continuation of [Indy server supports SSL 2, but it should not](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44727830/).

Using Delphi XE Berlin 10.1, I have found two CipherList strings that meet the basic requirements of level A encryption strength:

```
TLSv1:TLSv1.2:SSLv3:!RC4:!NULL-MD5:!NULL-SHA:!NULL-SHA256:!DES-CBC-SHA:!DES-CBC3-SHA:!IDEA-CBC-SHA
```

```
ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
```

Testing with Qualys SSLlabs shows the same results for them: they are strong, but:

- forward secrecy is not supported.
- some of the older browsers (in particular, IE8 on XP and Win7) will not connect (some of my users - government, hospitals - may still be using those. You may argue that those users have bigger problems than to worry about RC4 and DES, but that is not what this post is about).

When I check my bank's service with Qualys, I notice that they do support all of the old browsers.  My question is: how to configure Indy's `TIdServerIOHandlerSSLOpenSSL` so that my server will do the same?

In the current configuration, I have:

```
Method := sslvTLSv1_2;
SSLVersions := [sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2];
```

I notice that the Qualys report says that my server supports TLS 1.2 only, while my bank seems to support TLS 1.1 and TLS 1.0 as well.  They use an RSA2048 key with SHA256withRSA signature. But so do I.  I use the latest OpenSSL DLLs. The cipherList is from Hynek Sclawack (hynek.me/articles), updated 10 days ago.

And yet: no older browsers, no forward secrecy. What have I missed?

Comment: Qualys has a blog article about Forward Secrecy: [Configuring Apache, Nginx, and OpenSSL for Forward Secrecy](https://blog.qualys.com/ssllabs/2013/08/05/configuring-apache-nginx-and-openssl-for-forward-secrecy)

Comment: The only way an OpenSSL server can support multiple TLS versions is by using OpenSSL's SSLv23 wildcard protocol, which performs TLS version negotiation dynamically based on the client's handshake and server's configuration.  Indy uses SSLv23 when you have `Method=sslvSSLv23`. Setting `Method=sslvTLSv1_2` forces TLS 1.2 only (and sets `SSLVersions=[sslvTLSv1_2]`), but setting `SSLVersions=[sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2]` will set `Method=sslvSSLv23` and then disable SSLv2 and SSLv3 while leaving TLS 1.x enabled.

Comment: When I use method=sslvSSLv23 in combination with versions=[sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2] the SSLlabs test shows that TLS1.x protocols are supported. But also SSL 3.
If I read you correctly that should not be the case. So my code must be messed up somehow. I will search further. When I use method=sslvTLSv1_2 only the TLS1.2 protocol is supported - as expected.

Comment: Note that the Qualys blog starts with "This blog is obsolete."

Comment: I don't know what to tell you. Indy explicitly disables SSL3 when `Method=sslvSSLv23` and `sslvSSLv3` is not in `SSLVersions`, using `SSL_CTX_set_options(SSL_OP_NO_SSLv3)`.

Comment: I believe you, but that is weird then.
In Form.onCreate I set ´SSLoptions.SSLversions:=[sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2]´ (and verify with F7 in IDE).
Next I set ´method:=sslvSSLv23´ (idem).
And now the SSLoptions have changed into ´[sslvSSLv2,sslvSSLv3,sslvTLSv1,sslvTLSv1_1,sslvTLSv1_2]´.
And these settings are not modified when subsequently ´server.active:=true´ is executed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/147747/discussion-between-user3212191-and-remy-lebeau).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few months ago my tests on Qualys Labs got an A grade, including Forward Secrecy. This was the CipherList used (Cipher List is too long for a comment, so here it goes as an answer):

```
CipherList := 'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:'+            
  'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:'+            
  'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:'+                
  'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:'+                
  'ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:'+                   
  'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:'+                   
  'DHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:'+              
  'DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA256:'+                  
  'DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA:'+                     
  'DHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:'+              
  'DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA256:'+                  
  'DHE-RSA-AES128-SHA:'+                     
  'DES-CBC3-SHA:'+                           
  '!ADH:!EXP:!RC4:!eNULL@STRENGTH';
```

Comment: I tried those ciphers. Same result as with the list I showed before.
The interesting thing is that SSLlabs shows the cipher suites it could employ. For my server it only shows TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_... even though your list includes ECDHE ciphers. And those are needed for forward security. But for my bank's site (my reference) the TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_... ciphers are listed.
I wonder now if I am using the correct DLL's. 
I've downloaded libeay32.dll and ssleay32.dll from http://indy.fulgan.com/SSL/ testing the 1.0.2k versions. Only the 386 ones want to bind (independent on 32/64 bit exe).